# Apply Windows authentication on ASP.NET core 2.2 published site without getting chrome Sign in dialog box

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication, windows-server-2016, applicationpoolidentity

Trying to implement **windows authentication** on my published **asp.net core 2.2** application.
Hosting server is **Windows server 2016** (IIS).
I would like to use the active directory logged in user account to authenticate the user on my application.

I'm getting the user details by these methods:

```
User.Identity.Name; //return null in local host, worked when IIS

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() // local host
```

I keep getting in the browser, the Sign in dialog box (although I would like to get rid of it, even when entering credentials - <username> + password - it doesn't authenticated).

1. I would like to get rid of it
2. Stop getting error 401 - unauthorized

I've configured what ever I was advised - both IIS and browser, but still - keep getting it:

**Browser:**

1. Browser security - Entered the host IP address to the trusted sites

**IIS:**

1. Set Authentication => enable Windows Authentication to true.
2. Through web.config - set "forwardWindowsAuthToken" to "true".

**Site Configuration:**

1. In the IIS site configuration (applicationHost) - system.webserver -> Security -> Authentication -> windows authentication -> "UseKernelmode" = "true"

**ApplicationPool:**

1. .NET CLR Vesrion = "No Managed Code"
2. Managed Pipeline Mode = " Integrated"
   event tried to change in the "advanced settings" the **Identity** from "**ApplicationPoolIdentity**" to "**NetworkService**"

**NTFS permissions:**

1. Set basic and defaults Permissions to the account<Server host Name>\IIS_IUSRS on the server published code directory: Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read.
   Maybe the problem is here - because the IIS_IUSRS  account is defined in the server and not in the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to solve the problem:

1. Open iis and in Windows Authentication, Right-Click to set the Providers, set the NTLM to be FIRST.
2. Check that under Advanced Settings... the Extended Protection is Accept and Enable Kernel-mode authentication is checked.

[image][image]